# Uniform convergence of function $e^{-t(x+1)}(\cos xt)\frac t{t+x^2} \rightarrow e^{-t}$

Tags: real-analysis

The problem is to show that $F(x,t) = e^{-t(x+1)}(\cos xt)\frac t{t+x^2} \rightarrow e^{-t}$ uniformly in {$t \ge 0$} as $x \rightarrow 0$.  I suspect that this statement is incorrect.  First of all, when $t = 0$, the function converges to $0$, and not $e^{-0} = 1$.

If I change the interval for $t$ to {$t>0$}, the statement still does not appear to be true.  The function converges pointwise, but not uniformly.  If it converged uniformly, then for each $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta >0$ such that

$|e^{-t(x+1)}(\cos xt)\frac t{t+x^2}-e^{-t}| < \epsilon$ if $|x| < \delta$

for all $t>0$.  However, given any $x$, I can make $F(x,t)$ as close to $0$ as I want by making $t$ sufficiently small.  Hence the expression above will not be less than $\epsilon$ for all $t>0$.

Am I missing something?  Or is there a way to fix this problem to make it correct other than stating that it converges uniformly in {$t \ge c > 0$} as $x \rightarrow 0$?

Comment: You have it correct!

Comment: Thank you for confirming what I suspected.

Comment: You're welcome.  You not only suspected it, you correctly verified your suspicion. Well done!  - Mark